# I can't connect to my running ubuntu ec2 instance

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, ssh, amazon-ec2

I've been trying to connect to my running instance for a while now and nothing is working, I tried generating a public key and importing it. that didn't work.

Then I downloaded the .pem file from aws. But it always asks me for a passphrase everytime, then tells me passphrase is invalid. I've googled and tried everything I've seen on the internet but none of them are working for me.

Here's the output of `ssh -vvvi seun-ubuntu.pem ubuntu@<public_ip>`:

```
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "35.164.99.195" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 35.164.99.195 [35.164.99.195] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file seun-ubuntu.pem type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file seun-ubuntu.pem-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to 35.164.99.195:22 as 'ubuntu'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/seunlanlege/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/seunlanlege/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 35.164.99.195
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:y7TWEyrhSMy5AXY82NrlHJCxDkJ8Ybsv5ObgVsDJEtc
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/seunlanlege/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/seunlanlege/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 35.164.99.195
debug1: Host '35.164.99.195' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/seunlanlege/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: key: seunlanlege@gmail.com (0x55da98116d50), agent
debug2: key: seun-ubuntu.pem ((nil)), explicit
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: seunlanlege@gmail.com
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: seun-ubuntu.pem
Enter passphrase for key 'seun-ubuntu.pem':
```

Please help, I've been at this for an hour now. I have experience with how ssh keys work as I've used digitalocean before but I'm a beginner with AWS and this is very frustrating.

Comment: Could be an issue with permissions or ownership of your private key (pem) file. Is the ubuntu user the owner of the pem file?

Comment: Check that your local .pem file is set to 400, it looks like your security group is ok as there is no connection refused error.

Comment: yes, it is `-r-------- 1 seunlanlege seunlanlege 1696 Apr 23 22:20 seun-ubuntu.pem`

Comment: @SeunLanLege Are you trying to ssh from the user that has ownership of that .pem file? If not, are you able to enter anything when it asks for a password for that key?

Comment: Voting to close this question as off-topic. Please note that Stackoverflow is for programming related questions only. Please review the [help/on-topic] for what topics can be asked here. The help also has suggestions for other SE sites where this question may be appropriate.

Comment: Did you edit the .pem file in any way, or is it exactly as downloaded from AWS? Sometimes opening the file then using Copy & Paste impacts line-breaks and can ruin the format of the file. Also, did you generate the Key and link it to your instance *before* the instance was launched, or did you generate the Key *after* the instance was launched?

Comment: "Then I downloaded the .pem file from aws." It's not possible to download a `.pem` file from AWS except at the time you created the key pair. Since you say the instance was launched before you downloaded the `.pem`, the instance does not have the newly-generated `.pem` on it at all. It has some other `.pem` on it that existed at the time of the creation of the EC2 instance. Find that and use it.

Comment: If nothing works, either recreate your EC2 instance or "fix" them using this method
https://aws.amazon.com/articles/5213606968661598

Comment: So i found the problem, i downloaded the .pem via uget. and for some reason, it's contents where html and not an rsa key. I disabled uget and created another key. then downloaded via chrome and it worked. Thanks @JohnRotenstein for suggesting the .pem could've been invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get prompted for the password of a `.pem` file and you know that there is no password on the key, it's normally an indication that `ssh` can't read the file properly.

I've seen this happen when somebody did a Copy & Paste and had incorrect linebreak characters.

If you open the file in a text editor, the lines should all be of the same length except the last one, with headers like this:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEowIBAAKCAQEAgERw9liYOkOAPNrnupzGEMA9dLTIKmSp98F4eveqLq3WH9sIc2FZpzGT3HEm
qBFGvNkgywPZommXsamZ53mt3KJ1FTAZ5roojScbjawzjg5B+JhRHpj6bVDapSZl1bM0CQPLxWK2
LbvBHjfXtFJEndxPk7PQxSnYsvOqwpdggWPwLmbpyadmzdfrpCcCgYEAm3U6jhReSOqDbEG8gAMi
...
8VVrSccLeNVP2KapL6VsXO6lZmuCgz0B9RghrO+CQ/4okoZO53wc+UdJkLX9s5d+gaR3
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

If the file looks different, try to obtain another copy of the key.